# How do I get the vertices on the shortest path using igraph?

Tags: python, shortest-path, igraph

I'm using `igraph` to generate a matrix of shortest path distances between pairs of vertices but I can't figure out how to return the vertices. So far I have:

```
path_length_matrix = ig_graph.shortest_paths_dijkstra(None,None,"distance", "ALL")
```

I'm looking for a function which returns a matrix of paths like the matrix of distances but I can't see anything in the [igraph documentation](http://packages.python.org/python-igraph/igraph.Graph-class.html) which shows how to get the paths.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The function you need is `get_shortest_paths` I believe. See https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph.GraphBase.html#get_shortest_paths

You need to call it individually for each source vertex, and it will give you only a single (arbitrary) shortest path for each pair of nodes. If you need all shortest paths, then see `get_all_shortest_paths`: https://igraph.org/python/api/latest/igraph.GraphBase.html#get_all_shortest_paths

Comment: That looks like it should help, although there is a warning not to use this class at the top and to use `igraph.Graph` instead. I guess this function hasn't been added to `igraph.Graph` yet.

Comment: Doesn't `igraph.Graph` inherit methods from `igraph.GraphBase`? I am not sure myself, just asking....

Comment: @GaborCsardi, you are not sure when you authored those classes :D

Comment: I did not, actually.

Comment: both links are broken

Answer (score 4):

I do this

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph([(0,1), (0,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,2), (2,5), (5,0), (6,3), (5,6)])
g.vs["name"] = ["Alice", "Bob", "Claire", "Dennis", "Esther", "Frank", "George"]
#You could create Vertexes like g.add_vertex(name="Bill") 
path=g.get_shortest_paths("Alice",to="Frank",mode=OUT,output='vpath')
for n in path[0]:
    print("{}".format(g.vs[n]['name']))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to find shortest path for weighted directed graph (DAG).
So this what I figured out:

```
import igraph
from igraph import *
g = Graph(directed=True)
g.add_vertices(3)
g.vs["name"]=["GO:1234567","GO:6789056","GO:5674321"]
g.es["weight"]=1
g['GO:1234567','GO:6789056']=1
g['GO:6789056','GO:5674321']=5
weight=g.es["weight"]
print weight
print g.degree(mode="in") 
print g.shortest_paths_dijkstra(source="GO:1234567", target="GO:5674321", 
    weights=weight, mode=OUT)
```